# Sending POST request with custom headers

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest, http-post

I'm trying to send a `POST` request with parameters and a body (via C# for Windows Phone). In order to send parameters, I need to use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for the Content-Type header.

Only problem is the server I'm communicating with expects me to have `Content-Type` set to something else (a custom value).

Basically for a link in the form of `ip/path/file?param1=value1&param2=value2`, sent via POST with the POST body being JSON content, I need to set `Content-Type` to something custom, but still have the parameters sent.

Is there any conceivable way of doing this? I realize it's a bit of a paradox. Changing the server API to respond to other `Content-Type` headers is not possible.

Comment: Are you sure it's the content type header and not authorization header? That seems weird to be honest.

Comment: My Authorization header consists of a token I get correctly via a GET request. Server expects to see a custom Content-Type equal to something custom, but it also expects to get some parameters in the URL link. If I try to send parameters in the body of the request I get a "Not Authorized" response because of missing parameters, and if I try to set the content type to anything else other than what the server expects, I get a 415 "Unsupported Content-Type header value" error.

Comment: I'm using JMeter to test all requests using test cases provided by the QA team, and in JMeter it's working fine. That in itself is strange...  Problems arise when trying to translate requests to C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer shortly after posting the question. It seems that if I construct the URL string to include the actual parameters it works like a charm.

This is oppposed to the situation where I would add parameters problematically via HTTP Requests api.

Answer (score 1):

Some headers can be set using API properties only.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.androidlost.com/androidlost/greet");
request.ContentType = "text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=utf-8";
```

Comment: I'm doing just that. Setting ContentType via the normal HTTP WebRequest API. Using text/x-gwt-rpc isn't working. Basically I need to send a POST request with Parameters and a Body, but with Content-Type set to something custom. C# insists I use application/x-www-form-urlencoded for any parameter sending, and I can't do that since the server expects some other Content Type.